# coverity 2017.07 segfaults on debian buster and stretch

Tags: coverity

I was trying to update my coverity setup and I can't even run `cov-build --help` without it segfaulting.  See the following asciinema for reproduction steps.  I forgot to show that the md5sum matches in the asciinema, but I assure you it does.

I did the same thing in a docker container running debian stretch and got the same results.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

https://asciinema.org/a/FXLDkV3vLNnlxhGkr0UwNyb4o

Answer (score 2):

Do you have the emulation of deprecated vsyscall enabled?

This isn't the case by default since kernel version 4.8.x and is required for their binaries to work at the moment.

```
# sysctl vsyscall=emulate
```

You could also modify your boot loader to start your kernel with this parameter:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet vsyscall=emulate"
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like I need to set it as a boot option as I'm getting the following error message

`$ sudo sysctl vsyscall=emulate`
`sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/vsyscall: No such file or directory`

Comment: Indeed, just tried it in Debian *testing* and `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet vsyscall=emulate"` seems to work.